# PaperTrail how to get the original version - When we have ignored attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paper-trail-gem

Please suggest me to achieve the following -

**Use Case:**

```
   class Widget
     # attributes :name, :address
     has_paper_trail ignore: [:name]
   end
```

Step 1: `Widget.create(name: "test1", address: "address1")` it will create **Version 1** with object as nil

Step 2: When I update ignored field `widget.update(name: 'test2')` It won't create any version

Step 3: `widget.update(address: 'address2')` field will create **Version 2**

When I use this - `widget.versions.second&.reify || widget` return  `widget(name: "test2", address: "address1") not widget(name: "test1", address: "address1")`

I want to get original version when it got created `widget(name: "test1", address: "address1")`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I know there was some discussion about adding an `original_version` method to paper trail but I don't know if that's happened or if your app's version has it.

You can always do

```
widget.versions.second&.reify || widget
```

That will return to reify from the first modification made, but if there's no first modification it just returns the widget as is (as there's been no changes).

Comment: Thanks for the response @steveturczyn . In my case.
Step 1 -> create widget => Version 1
Step 2 -> Update ignored field
Step 3 -> Update field to create version => Version 2

when I use this - widget.versions.second&.reify || widget -- It will go to the previous version contain ignored field update 

But I want to get the original version when it got created.

Comment: Are you sure? Did you try it?  It should have brought you to original version.

Comment: It will @steve but Original version contain ignored field changes also. But I want a same item created at first time. Please have a look updated use case above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, that's pretty hairy.  The only way I can think of doing it is by overriding the update method...

```
def update(arguments = {})
  if (arguments.keys - [:name]).present? && !arguments.has_key?(:name)
    arguments[:name] = name.dup
  end
  super(arguments)
end
```

Which will force the :name to be recorded whenever non-name values are updated.

Then you can do

```
widget.versions.second&.reify || widget
```